# Why do I keep getting operation attribute error in my tensor flow codes

Tags: python, tensorflow

I try to build a hidden layer of neural network with tensorflow but I keep getting error message

> "Operation" object has no attribute "dtype".

This is where the code throws the error:

```
codings = tf.layers.dense(X, n_hidden, name="hidden")
```

This is the entire script

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image

data = []
test2 = Image.open("./ters/test2.jpg")
prepared_data = np.asarray(test2.resize((800, 1000), Image.ANTIALIAS))
data.append(prepared_data)
data = np.asarray(data)

saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("./my_model.ckpt.meta")

batch_size, height, width, channels = data.shape

n_hidden = 400
X = tf.get_default_graph().get_operation_by_name("Placeholder")
training_op = tf.get_default_graph().get_operation_by_name("train/Adam")
codings = tf.layers.dense(X, n_hidden, tf.float32)

n_iterations = 5

with tf.Session() as sess:
saver.restore(sess, "./my_model.ckpt")
sess.run(training_op)
test_img = codings.eval(feed_dict={X: X_test})

print(test_img)
```

Note:
I have already trained the model and named it *my_model.ckpt* and I tried importing and using it.
This is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "using_img_cleaner.py", line 36, in <module>
    codings = tf.layers.dense(X, n_hidden, tf.float32)
  File "/home/exceptions/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/core.py", line 250, in dense
    dtype=inputs.dtype.base_dtype,
AttributeError: 'Operation' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

Comment: Can you post the full code in order for me to reproduce the error?

Comment: okay, let me edit the question

Comment: So, you trained the model using a separate script and it worked, and this is a script that you are using to retrain your model?

Comment: Exactly. This is where the error arises. Not retrain the model but to use it on another image as a test file

Comment: Then you don't need to create the hidden layer again, it is already present in the graph when you are loading the meta graph. Just load the ops you need (`X` and `training_op`) and that should be it.

Comment: I've done that but I don't seem to find a way to use evaluation on the model. I.e to use .eval(feed_dict={X:X_test}). Maybe I'm doing the whole thing wrong